# Is a German BahnCard valid in Switzerland?

Tags: trains, germany, switzerland

Deutsche Bahn offers a "[BahnCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BahnCard)" which offers the holder a 25, 50, or 100% discount on Deutsche Bahn rail tickets.

The wiki page mentions that, due to the "TEE Rail Alliance", the DB BahnCard 25 and BahnCard 50 can be used to get a discount on a trip in Switzerland that begins in Germany.

Is the BahnCard 25/50 also valid for a discount on a journey on Swiss trains that takes place entirely within Switzerland?

Comment: Switzerland is not that big! I mean unless you go from Geneva to Italy, I think you can check the price of getting from a German border town to your final destination. Check very early, prices are very low compared to Swiss tickets (I paid 30 euros for Geneva-Nuremberg while Geneva-Basel is probably twice the price)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No!

> Profitieren Sie als BahnCard-Inhaber von 25% Ermäßigung auf den
>   Normalpreis der Auslandsstrecke bei grenzüberschreitenden Reisen in
>   über 30 europäischen Länder.
>
> Die Ermäßigung wird auch im Anschluss an Globalpreise (z.B. Thalys),
>   gewährt - nicht aber im reinen Binnenverkehr des fremden Landes.

The last sentence says 'not valid for travel on trains exclusively in a foreign country'.

You can only use the discount if you begin your journey in Germany and cross into Switzerland.

Source: [Deutsche Bahn](http://bahn.de/p/view/bahncard/vorteile/railplus.shtml)

Comment: http://www.bahn.de/p/view/bahncard/vorteile/railplus.shtml

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: Your answer will be even better if you include the link in your comment in the answer itself.

Comment: **That's one impressive example of german langue...** Honestly, these four lines are so contrived that it would be easier for me to read any english translation. I'm German.

Comment: That quote definitely needs a [sic!], it is so bad …

Comment: Even if the second restriction did not apply: Switzerland is not among the 23 countries (as of July 2023) where the Bahncard can be used for international journeys.  And from December 2023, Bahncard will cease being recognised abroad entirely.